# How to access ICY-metadata with libvlc

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc, python-vlc

Is it possible to access the ICY-metadata over the libvlc interface?
I'm using the python-vlc bindings.

```
import vlc
import time

url = "http://fritz.de/livemp3"

instance = vlc.Instance("--no-xlib")
player = instance.media_player_new()
player.set_media(instance.media_new(url))
player.play()

time.sleep(0.5)

print("meta 0")
print(player.get_media().get_meta(0))

print("track info")
print(player.get_media().get_tracks_info())
```

I thought it is maybe `get_meta` and with the Enum value 0 which should be title. But this returns just part of the url.

And `get_tracks_info` is just a number.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get that from the meta data libvlc APIs. The VLC app only shows ICY info in the verbose debug logs, don't think you have other options.

Comment: The show it also in the title bar at least for me under linux. (So that is why I'm hoping that it is accessible from the libvlc)

Comment: Not exposed by libvlc I'm afraid https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=146556&p=485711&hilit=ICY+metadata#p485711